# .css not working in JQuery function chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a function to take a the value from a name field on a website and use it to auto fill the email field. In addition I added a quick flash of yellow to show the user that the field was automatically updated.

In this spaced out example everything works fine.

```
$(function() {
  $("#name").on("change", function(){

  let name = $(this).val();

  let spIndex = name.indexOf(" ");

  let email = name.substr(0, spIndex) + name.substr(spIndex+1, 1) + "@example.com";

  $("#email").val(email.toLowerCase());

  $("#email").css({
  "transition": "background-color 0.5s",
  "background-color": "#f9ff60"
  });

  setTimeout(function(){$("#email").css({"background-color":"#fff"});}, 400);

  });

});
```

I only noticed the problem when I tried to chain the function (Yes I know the first way makes more sense, I just wanted to try it out). For some reason the `.css()` function does not do anything.

```
$(function() {
  $("#name").on("change", function() {
    $("#email").val(($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).val().indexOf(" ")) + 
      $(this).val().substr($(this).val().indexOf(" ")+1, 1) + "@example.com").toLowerCase())
      .css({
        "transition": "background-color: 500",
        "background-color": "#f9ff60"
      })
     .delay(400)
     .css({
       "background-color": "#fff"
     });
  });
});
```

Additionally I tried to add another `.val()` function at the end of the chain to check if it made it all the way through, and it did work, but not css was change.

Since I know I can do it the first way I am not asking to use it, but rather just for future note if I do end up using the `.css()` function in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Delay is used in relation to functions of jquery that use it's internal animation queues.  It is not a replacement for a timeout for all things.  Given your case, I believe since css() does not use the animation queue that it is simply applying the css statements so fast that you are not seeing any effect.

Answer (score 0):

As per the JQuery Effects API, you can find [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) there's an option to highlight a specific element.

By linking JQuery UI underneath your main JQuery script tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You can do as such:

```
$(this).val().substr($(this).val().indexOf(" ")+1, 1) + "@example.com").toLowerCase()).toggle("highlight");
```